# Train Communication (networking)

Tags: computer-networks, network-topology

I have an essay question and I just want to make sure I have things right.

2 trains need to be able to communicate with eachother at any time.

Based on research i've settles on a wired network running along the tracks, with wireless access points. These converge on a central location which houses the switches/router to redirect comms.

The trains themselves have a router with WAP's so the driver can send comms from anywhere on the train.

What i'm struggling with is the idea that the train system is a LAN and so are the trains - would the onboard router connect to the trackside WAP's to send the messages?

I've seen that bridges can be used for similar but am unsure if that's what's needed in this scneario

Comment: This seems to be a question about network engineering rather than computer science. It will also depend very much on where in the world these trains are. If they're in a large city, GSM might work fine; if they're in the middle of Siberia, that won't be an option.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That, or it is a question on [softwareengineering.se]